# Select dropdown cutting text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using reactJs to make a webapp. However I tried to make a select drowdown but for some reason its text looks like this:

[image]

(I'm not able to post the picture because I don't have enough reputation)

Here's my HTML inside my JS render

```
               <div className="results" id="order" onChange={(event) => this.handleSelect(event,"order")}>
                    <select id="order-select" defaultValue={Constants.NEWEST_PUBLICATION}>
                        <option disabled value={Constants.NO_ORDER}>{t('list.noOrder')}</option>
                        <option value={Constants.NEWEST_PUBLICATION}>{t('list.newest')}</option>
                        <option value={Constants.OLDEST_PUBLICATION}>{t('list.oldest')}</option>
                        <option value={Constants.ASCENDANT_ORDER}>{t('list.lowest')}</option>
                        <option value={Constants.DESCENDANT_ORDER}>{t('list.highest')}</option>                 
                    </select>
                    <h3 id="order-title-select">{t('list.order')}</h3>
                </div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.results {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}

#order-title-select {
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    margin-top: 30px !important;
    float: right;
}

#order {
    float: right;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    width: 30%;
}

#order-title {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 25px !important;
    margin-top: 25px !important;
}


#order-select {
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-top: 23px;
    border: 1px solid #FD8907;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #555;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 40%; 
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;

}

#order-select option {
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: can you copy the complied html from the browser

Comment: Have you attempted changing the height to something like `height: fit-content`? Looks like your display value isn't affecting the outer element.

Comment: @AymanMorsy how can I do that?

Comment: @mdawsondev Ok that seems to be it! Thanks

Comment: right click on this element and choose inspect > the browser will highlight it right click then choose `edit as html`  and copy

Comment: @Someone reduce your margins (especially the margin-top) for a start - 23px is v large and is pushing your text down out of sight

Comment: @RachelGallen I've tried that but nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS file;

```
select {
  height: fit-content;
}
```

or if you can't use `fit-content` go with a fixed value

```
select {
  height: 100px; // adjust accordingly
}
```

I am guessing your height is being clipped

Comment: take care `height: fit-content` has a partial support

Comment: i have updated my answer, take a look again. You can use fixed values as well.